# How to determine current users who are logged in using a specific domain?

Tags: shell, grep, csh

I want to know How to determine current users who are logged in using a specific domain?

For example, here is the question. Please tell according to it using the grep command and use of wc.

> **Question:** Write a C shell script called `countkpu` which determines how many of the currently logged in users are logged in from a computer on the kwantlen.ca domain.
>
> To do this, note the `who` command will show each user who is logged in along with identification of their computer.
>
> You can feed this information to the `grep` command, to only display strings that contain the "kwantlen.ca". You can then further feed this output to the `wc` command, which can be used in such a way to just count lines of output.

HERE IS WHAT I DID:

```
grep `hostname` /etc/hosts
```

results:

```
10.65.36.35    gator    gator.kwantlen.ca   loghost
```

The Problem is how will I combine the `who` command as in the question? I mean it is not telling who is logged in using this domain.

Comment: Please don't make alternate accounts to work around question bans. I reopened your original question and merged the activity here into it; use that account/thread to try and find an answer to your question. I'm removing this account